# ServiceStack - Set serialize function within a scope

Tags: servicestack

I currently scope some configuration values to prevent any changes being made globally:

```
 using(var scope = JsConfig.BeginScope()) 
 {
    scope.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
    scope.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    // perform serialization
 }
```

However I now need to format Guids with a dash which requires me to change the serialize function for guids as below:

```
 JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString("D");
```

Is is possible to make this change within a scope as with the other configuration settings above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot scope it. But you can add then remove the serialization methods as you need them managing the scope yourself.

```
JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString("D");
Debug.WriteLine(new Guid().ToJson());

JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = null;
Debug.WriteLine(new Guid().ToJson());
```

This will output:

```
"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
"00000000000000000000000000000000"
```